# Update Parse User info to keep track of player scores in kivy app

Tags: python, python-2.7, parse-platform, kivy

we would like to use parse to track our user's scores in our kivy app. Our app requires an encoded secure login so when we try to link the User's parse information (e.g., objectId, username, etc) to their score we get the following error: parse_rest.core.ResourceRequestLoginRequired: save requires a logged-in session

This message is thrown by line 26 in the parse_rest user.py. Our current code attempts to feed parse the sessionToken but it doesn't work for some reason. Please help us figure out how to get this code to work:

main.py (Note: our session token is identified and set to equal 'sessionToken' in our LoginScreen class. we know this works because we can use 'print LoginScreen.sessionToken' to print the session token when executing a method in any of the app's classes)

```
def game_score(self):
    userScore = User(score="")

    import json,httplib
    connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
    connection.connect()
    connection.request('PUT', '/1/users/objectId', userScore.save(), 
    {"X-Parse-Application-Id": "Parse_app_id",
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "Parse_rest_API_key",
    "X-Parse-Session-Token": LoginScreen.sessionToken})

    gameScore = GameScore(score='user_score_pulled_from_game_screen')
    gameScore.save()
    User.score = gameScore


    import json,httplib
    connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
    connection.connect()
    connection.request('PUT', '/1/users/objectId', userScore.save(), 
    {"X-Parse-Application-Id": "Parse_app_id",
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "Parse_rest_API_key",
    "X-Parse-Session-Token": LoginScreen.sessionToken})

pass
```

As an fyi, the code structure we're using comes from the "updating users" section of the Parse documentation: https://parse.com/docs/rest

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after some work we came to a more robust solution that directly ties a gameScores column in the User table to the gameScore table:

```
def update_game_score(self):
    user = User.login(username, password)

    try:
        user.gameScores
    except AttributeError:
        gameScore = GameScore(TotalScore=self.manager.get_screen('game_home_screen').score)
        gameScore.save()
        user.gameScores = gameScore
        user.save()
    else:
        gameScore = user.gameScores
        gameScore.TotalScore += self.manager.get_screen('game_home_screen').score
        gameScore.save()
```

The approach for how to do this comes from the Users section of the ParsePy documentation: https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using [ParsePy](https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy), creating a [One-to-One](https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide#onetoone) relationship between User and GameScore. The login function will prevent the ResourceRequestLoginRequired error you received. Furthermore, with this method, no session token is required.

```
def update_game_score(self):    
        user = User.login(<username>, <password>)
        gameScore = GameScore(score='user_score_pulled_from_game_screen')
        gameScore.save()
        user.gameScores = gameScore
        user.save()
```